# have razor text box default value disappear

Tags: razor, textbox

I have a form with two text boxes. What I would like is when the user clicks in the text boxes the default values disappears. I am using razor so not sure how to add the onfocus event I think I need.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "newsletterform" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @Value = "Name"})

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @Value = "Email"})

    <input type="submit" class="newsletterGo" value="Go" />
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can user the [placeholder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Forms_in_HTML#The_placeholder_attribute) attribute. An example of it is the search box at the top of this page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "newsletterform" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { placeholder = "Default Name"})

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "person@example.com"})

    <input type="submit" class="newsletterGo" value="Go" />
}
```

Also, you don't need to specify the `@Value` attribute. The HTML helpers take care of setting the input values for you.